# Why is my SVG sprite id reference not loading the corresponding svg?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, sprite

I am using the SVG Sprite system in vanilla JS to load two SVGs on to my page. I have contained both SVGs in one icons.svg file using https://svgsprit.es/ service:

```html
<svg width="0" height="0" class="hidden">
  <symbol viewBox="0 0 0 0" id="delete">
    <symbol viewBox="0 0 0 0" id="delete">
      <symbol fill="#000000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" id="edit">
        <path d="M 18.414062 2 C 18.158062 2 17.902031 2.0979687 17.707031 2.2929688 L 15.707031 4.2929688 L 14.292969 5.7070312 L 3 17 L 3 21 L 7 21 L 21.707031 6.2929688 C 22.098031 5.9019687 22.098031 5.2689063 21.707031 4.8789062 L 19.121094 2.2929688 C 18.926094 2.0979687 18.670063 2 18.414062 2 z M 18.414062 4.4140625 L 19.585938 5.5859375 L 18.292969 6.8789062 L 17.121094 5.7070312 L 18.414062 4.4140625 z M 15.707031 7.1210938 L 16.878906 8.2929688 L 6.171875 19 L 5 19 L 5 17.828125 L 15.707031 7.1210938 z"></path>
      </symbol>
    </symbol>
  </symbol>
  <symbol viewBox="0 0 0 0" id="edit">
    <symbol fill="#000000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" id="edit">
      <path d="M 18.414062 2 C 18.158062 2 17.902031 2.0979687 17.707031 2.2929688 L 15.707031 4.2929688 L 14.292969 5.7070312 L 3 17 L 3 21 L 7 21 L 21.707031 6.2929688 C 22.098031 5.9019687 22.098031 5.2689063 21.707031 4.8789062 L 19.121094 2.2929688 C 18.926094 2.0979687 18.670063 2 18.414062 2 z M 18.414062 4.4140625 L 19.585938 5.5859375 L 18.292969 6.8789062 L 17.121094 5.7070312 L 18.414062 4.4140625 z M 15.707031 7.1210938 L 16.878906 8.2929688 L 6.171875 19 L 5 19 L 5 17.828125 L 15.707031 7.1210938 z"></path>
    </symbol>
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

When I add the HTML through dynamic JS I use:

```js
const container = document.createElement('div');

//add edit icon
const editIcon = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
editIcon.classList.add('icon');
const use = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "use");
use.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', 'images/icons.svg#edit');
editIcon.appendChild(use);

//add delete icon
const deleteIcon = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
deleteIcon.classList.add('icon');
const use2 = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "use");
use2.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', 'images/icons.svg#delete');
deleteIcon.appendChild(use2);

container.appendChild(editIcon);
container.appendChild(deleteIcon);
```

but only the edit icon appears successfully? I notice that the delete SVG has two symbol tags each with an id - am I referencing it wrong in my JS?

**and yes I know xlink:href is deprecated! this is just a small project for learning so browser compatibility is not highly important

Comment: Just asking: why do you have 3 (three) <symbol> elements nested one in each other?

Comment: because I'm not very familiar with SVGs I used this service for combining them and referencing them: https://svgsprit.es/ so that's the combined SVG file it generated

Answer (score 2):

Your sprite file is wonky.  You should not have multiple nested `<symbol>` elements.

```
  <symbol viewBox="0 0 0 0" id="delete">
    <symbol viewBox="0 0 0 0" id="delete">
```

Each icon should only have one.

The reason your "delete" icon is not showing is because, when the browser tries to find the `"delete"` symbol, it has two that have `id="delete"`. That is illegal for a start, because `id` attributes *must be unique*.

It will choose one of them. In this case it doesn't matter which one it chooses. That's because all that either "delete" symbol contains is a `<symbol>` element. Which is effectively nothing, because `<symbol>` elements by themselves are not rendered. They are only rendered when referenced by a `<use>`.

You got lucky with the "edit" symbol, because you have *three* of those.  But luckily your browser is probably picking the first `id` match it finds.  And for `id="edit"` the first one is three levels down inside the nested `<symbol id="delete">` ones.

In other words, your sprite file looks like this to the browser

```
<svg width="0" height="0" class="hidden">
  <symbol viewBox="0 0 0 0" id="delete">
  </symbol>
  <symbol fill="#000000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" id="edit">
    <path d="M 18.414062 2 C 18.158062 2 17.902031 2.0979687 17.707031 2.2929688 L 15.707031 4.2929688 L 14.292969 5.7070312 L 3 17 L 3 21 L 7 21 L 21.707031 6.2929688 C 22.098031 5.9019687 22.098031 5.2689063 21.707031 4.8789062 L 19.121094 2.2929688 C 18.926094 2.0979687 18.670063 2 18.414062 2 z M 18.414062 4.4140625 L 19.585938 5.5859375 L 18.292969 6.8789062 L 17.121094 5.7070312 L 18.414062 4.4140625 z M 15.707031 7.1210938 L 16.878906 8.2929688 L 6.171875 19 L 5 19 L 5 17.828125 L 15.707031 7.1210938 z"></path>
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

Fix the nested symbol problem. It looks like you are passing, to that utility, SVG files that already contain only symbols. So it is simply wrapping symbols in other symbols.

I expect you should be passing renderable SVGs to that utility.
If your SVG files don't render anything when opened with a browser, they are probably already a "sprite sheet". Only use SVGs that display something when opened in a browser.

For your immediate problem, try this manually fixed file instead.

```html
<svg width="0" height="0" class="hidden">
  <symbol fill="#000000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" id="delete">
    <path d="M 18.414062 2 C 18.158062 2 17.902031 2.0979687 17.707031 2.2929688 L 15.707031 4.2929688 L 14.292969 5.7070312 L 3 17 L 3 21 L 7 21 L 21.707031 6.2929688 C 22.098031 5.9019687 22.098031 5.2689063 21.707031 4.8789062 L 19.121094 2.2929688 C 18.926094 2.0979687 18.670063 2 18.414062 2 z M 18.414062 4.4140625 L 19.585938 5.5859375 L 18.292969 6.8789062 L 17.121094 5.7070312 L 18.414062 4.4140625 z M 15.707031 7.1210938 L 16.878906 8.2929688 L 6.171875 19 L 5 19 L 5 17.828125 L 15.707031 7.1210938 z"></path>
  </symbol>
  <symbol fill="#000000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" id="edit">
    <path d="M 18.414062 2 C 18.158062 2 17.902031 2.0979687 17.707031 2.2929688 L 15.707031 4.2929688 L 14.292969 5.7070312 L 3 17 L 3 21 L 7 21 L 21.707031 6.2929688 C 22.098031 5.9019687 22.098031 5.2689063 21.707031 4.8789062 L 19.121094 2.2929688 C 18.926094 2.0979687 18.670063 2 18.414062 2 z M 18.414062 4.4140625 L 19.585938 5.5859375 L 18.292969 6.8789062 L 17.121094 5.7070312 L 18.414062 4.4140625 z M 15.707031 7.1210938 L 16.878906 8.2929688 L 6.171875 19 L 5 19 L 5 17.828125 L 15.707031 7.1210938 z"></path>
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I knew there was an issue with multiple ids!! :)